# How to disable past days in ZK Calendar?

Tags: zk, zk-calendar

I'm using ZK CE-9.0.0 & [zk-calendar-2.1.5 source code](https://www.zkoss.org/download/zkcalendar).

Currently all the days are enabled in the calendar.

I need to disable the past days (greyed out & no click event), from all the views(Day/Week/Month), but not able to find any such feature directly available.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks,

RAS

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such feature.

A workaround would be to disable event click on past days and change the color.

1 . Catch clicks in your controller :

```java
@Wire("#course-calendar")
private Calendars courseCalendar;

@Listen("onEventCreate = #course-calendar")
public void clickCreateEvent(CalendarsEvent event) {
    if (event.getBeginDate().before(new Date())) {
        // disable click if event is before now
    } else {
        //do something on event create
    }
}

@Listen("onEventEdit = #course-calendar")
public void clickEditEvent(CalendarsEvent event) {
    if (event.getBeginDate().before(new Date())) {
        // disable click if event is before now
    } else {
        // do something on event edit
    }
}
```

2. Grey out events on event creation :

```java
for (MyEvent me : myManager.getEvents()) {
    final SimpleCalendarEvent simpleCalendarEvent = new SimpleCalendarEvent();

    // set grey color event before now
    if (me.startDate < new Date()) {
        simpleCalendarEvent.setContentColor("#aaaaaa");
        simpleCalendarEvent.setHeaderColor("#aaaaaa");
        simpleCalendarEvent.setLocked(true);
    } else {
        simpleCalendarEvent.setContentColor("#4363d8");
        simpleCalendarEvent.setHeaderColor("#4363d8");
        simpleCalendarEvent.setLocked(false);
    }

    simpleCalendarEvent.setContent(me.getContent());
    simpleCalendarEvent.setBeginDate(me.startDate);
    simpleCalendarEvent.setEndDate(me.endDate);
    simpleCalendarEvent.setTitle(me.getTitle());

    getSimpleCalendarModel().add(simpleCalendarEvent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the question is to grey out past dates in the calendar & not the event. Preventing event is still easy but could you help me with greying out the past dates?

Comment: As stated this is a workaround as there is no constraint property on the ZK Calendar widget. If you really want to grey out full dates I'm afraid you have to go with some custom JavaScript to override the default behavior (see `zk.override()`). Or try some JavaScript/JQuery to parse the DOM and grey out the events after load. Maybe you can ask the ZK team for a better solution or fill a feature request.